# Configure Jenkin's SonarQube section using Job DSL (SONAR part missing)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-job-dsl, sonarqube-scan

I would like to configure Jenkins job using JobDSL. I define a variable `sonarProperties`. But **Invoke standalone analysis** part is missing.
Here is my configuration:

```
job('example') {

  def sonarProperties = '''\

  sonar.projectName=example

  sonar.projectVersion=1.0 

  ..

  ....

  '''.stripIndent()

  configure { sonar ->
    sonar / 'steps' << 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder' {
    properties ("$sonarProperties")
    javaOpts ''
    jdk '(Inherit From Job)'
    project ''
    task ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build steps are called `builders` in the XML configuration, so you need to replace `'steps'` by `'builders'`:

```
job('example') {
  configure {
    it / 'builders' << 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder' {
      properties ''
      javaOpts ''
      jdk '(Inherit From Job)'
      project ''
      task ''
    }
  }
}
```